# Phonegap: как заставить приложение запускаться строго в альбомной ориентации

Tags: phonegap, android

Независимо от типа устройства?..
Подозреваю, что в настройках Activity нужно что-то поправить, но пока не знаю что.
Подскажите, пожалуйста...

Comment: в манифесте указать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<activity android:screenOrientation="landscape" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden" android:name="YourActivity">
```

Если не хотите, чтобы ориентация менялась в процессе работы с активити, то в коде делаете примерно следующее:

```
@Override
public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
  // ignore orientation/keyboard change
  super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
}
```

Comment: то, что нужно, спасибо!